# Must a cuckoo filter use the next power of 2 for capacity?

Tags: filter, bloom-filter

Most cuckoo filter implementations I find have the capacity given from the caller increased to the next power of 2. I don't see in the paper anywhere that mentions "m" must be a power of two. Doing this results in a smaller average load factor.

Answer (score 1):

I think it isn't necessary to make capacity be the power of 2, but need some change in original method.

I searched this question previously. From [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/81876/cuckoo-filters-for-non-powers-of-2), Giuseppe Ottaviano thinks that 95% load factor given by the paper is relied on the table size be a power of 2, and load factor can be as bad as 50% otherwise. In there, D.W. promote an alternative formula that works with non-powers of two to solve this problem.

Although load factor doesn't rely on this(I will show in experiment below), using xor to choose candidate position does need cuckoo filter's capacity to be the power of 2. For example, if a fingerprint is 128  and has i1 = 32, hash(128) = 73, capacity = 100. `i2 = (i1 xor hash(fingerprint)) mod 100 = 5` instead of 105.

However, (105 xor hash(128)) mod 100 = 32, (5 xor hash(128)) mod 100 = 76. This means xor is not involution and will cause unexpected behaviour of cuckoo filter.

So in this situation it should use other involutional method to choose candidate position, like the one mentioned by D.W. `h_2(x) = hash(fingerprint) - h_1(x) mod n`.

Using data mentioned above, h1(x) = i1 = 32, hash(fingerprint) = 73, h2(x) = hash(fingerprint) - h1(x) = 41. And if hash(fingerprint) is less than h1(x) this method still works well. When h1(x) = 89, `h2(x) = (73-89) +100 = 84`, `h1(x) = (73-84) + 100 = 89`, it's still involution.

### Experiment

However, unlike xor, the alternative method may use same position as candidate. Still using `capacity = 100`, let `hash(fingerprint)=70` and `h1(x) = 85`, `h2(x) = hash(fingerprint) - h1(x) mod capacity = 85 = h1(x)`. This may have some influence on load factor as insertion is easier to fail.
I finished a cuckoo filter in go recently and did a test about the load factor.

I test many arguments with different capacities and bucketsizes. The unit test code is like below. It inserts random integer into cuckoo filter until the time of swap operations exceeds 500.

```golang
ckflter := cuckooFilter.CuckooFilter{}
ckflter.NewCuckooFilter(tt.args.capacity,tt.args.bucketSize)

over := false
for !over{
    element := rand.Intn(123456789000)
    ok,_ := ckflter.Add(bloomfilter.CFElement{ElementValue: strconv.Itoa(element)})
    if !ok{
        over = true
    }
}
fmt.Printf("Go test %s. Load factor %f",tt.name,ckflter.CalculateLoadFactor())
```

Results with different scenarios and arguments `(capacity,bucket_size)`. The capacity there means number of buckets in cuckoo filter. Bucket_size means number of fingerprint in one bucket, which is `b` in the paper.

The original data is post at the end of this answer. I calculate the average load factor for different bucket size and list below.

| situation | no use next power of 2 | make capacity next power of 2 | alternative method |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bucket size 1 | 0.393278 | 0.45014 | 0.40673 |
| bucket size 2 | 0.884191 | 0.878049 | 0.872531 |
| bucket size 4 | 0.970461 | 0.963951 | 0.964365 |
| bucket size 8 | 0.990913 | 0.989525 | 0.990372 |

`no use next power of 2` means calculating candidate position using xor even when capacity is not the power of 2. `alternative method` means no use next power of 2 and calculate candidate position using `h2(x) = hash(fingerprint) - h1(x) mod capacity` based on this [post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/81876/cuckoo-filters-for-non-powers-of-2)

Results show that the load factor in all three methods above is quite similar. So the alternative method is suitable for capacity that is not the power of 2.

PS:
I'm sorry I can't post my code on Internet as it is used by a company for commercial use. My implementation is based on [seiflotfy/cuckoofilter](https://github.com/seiflotfy/cuckoofilter)

PS2: origin data

| situation | no use next power of 2 | make capacity next power of 2 | alternative method |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (100,1) | 0.170000 | 0.656250 | 0.460000 |
| (128,1) | 0.539062 | 0.507812 | 0.546875 |
| (800,1) | 0.591250 | 0.417969 | 0.582500 |
| (1024,1) | 0.517578 | 0.488281 | 0.593750 |
| (10000,1) | 0.565100 | 0.491699 | 0.362200 |
| (16384,1) | 0.458374 | 0.505737 | 0.483582 |
| (100000,1) | 0.302530 | 0.451401 | 0.238530 |
| (131072,1) | 0.372047 | 0.341164 | 0.315895 |
| (1000000,1) | 0.145227 | 0.328159 | 0.125209 |
| (1048576,1) | 0.271615 | 0.312927 | 0.358754 |
| (100,2) | 0.935000 | 0.898438 | 0.885000 |
| (128,2) | 0.875000 | 0.898438 | 0.878906 |
| (800,2) | 0.887500 | 0.886719 | 0.872500 |
| (1024,2) | 0.868164 | 0.886230 | 0.894043 |
| (10000,2) | 0.916100 | 0.868591 | 0.871800 |
| (16384,2) | 0.868042 | 0.874420 | 0.871399 |
| (100000,2) | 0.895480 | 0.867485 | 0.861490 |
| (131072,2) | 0.867046 | 0.871918 | 0.861286 |
| (1000000,2) | 0.868981 | 0.863855 | 0.859927 |
| (1048576,2) | 0.860598 | 0.864397 | 0.868959 |
| (100,4) | 0.997500 | 0.974609 | 0.972500 |
| (128,4) | 0.980469 | 0.953125 | 0.972656 |
| (800,4) | 0.967187 | 0.975098 | 0.965000 |
| (1024,4) | 0.968750 | 0.973389 | 0.969971 |
| (10000,4) | 0.974725 | 0.967117 | 0.962075 |
| (16384,4) | 0.967117 | 0.965134 | 0.966309 |
| (100000,4) | 0.966420 | 0.960672 | 0.957130 |
| (131072,4) | 0.963726 | 0.960442 | 0.961651 |
| (1000000,4) | 0.959142 | 0.954331 | 0.956140 |
| (1048576,4) | 0.959578 | 0.955596 | 0.960214 |
| (100,8) | 1.000000 | 0.995117 | 1.000000 |
| (128,8) | 1.000000 | 0.989258 | 0.995117 |
| (800,8) | 0.992031 | 0.992798 | 0.988125 |
| (1024,8) | 0.994751 | 0.991211 | 0.993896 |
| (10000,8) | 0.987962 | 0.989838 | 0.989287 |
| (16384,8) | 0.991455 | 0.989746 | 0.991959 |
| (100000,8) | 0.985891 | 0.987493 | 0.987804 |
| (131072,8) | 0.987256 | 0.987178 | 0.987913 |
| (1000000,8) | 0.984694 | 0.986127 | 0.983695 |
| (1048576,8) | 0.985085 | 0.986484 | 0.985922 |
| total time | 14.74s | 15.22s | 14.49s |

Answer (score 0):

Yes. A cuckoo filter must use the next power of 2 (PO2) for capacity.

The reason is the calculation of the alternative location for the finger print uses the XOR operator. Since the filter has memory allocated to it, any number of buckets which isn't PO2, might land on a memory address outside of the allocated boundries.